# Can't show five Mat images all at once (C++, OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

In the code below, a method is used to input a Mat image and output an edited Mat image. The code works okay, although I am unable to have all five images on the screen at once, as when the code is run, only the last output image is displayed. Ideally, the code should display smaller, scaled down versions of each output image in the same window.

```
void method (Mat input)
{
    ...

    imshow("Output", output);
}

int main()
{
    img_1 = imread("img1.jpg");
    img_2 = imread("img2.jpg");
    img_3 = imread("img3.jpg");
    img_4 = imread("img4.jpg");
    img_5 = imread("img5.jpg");

    method(img_1);
    method(img_2);
    method(img_3);
    method(img_4);
    method(img_5);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want several highgui windows, each needs a distinct name:

```
void method (Mat input, const string & name)
{
    ...

    imshow(name, output);
}

 method(img_1, "image 1");
 method(img_2, "image 2");
 method(img_3, "image 3");
 // ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to scale down the Mat images with the resize() method, which is in the OpenCV documentation but doesn't appear to work at all like it's not part of my version of OpenCV (2.4.6).

Comment: Resize is definitely also available in your OpenCV version. Use it to resize, then stitch together the images by assigning them to different ROIs of a larger result image.